# Write and read RSA key from file : java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I'm new to Cryptography.

I would like to generate RSA key in java and write it to a file. Later I would like to read from that file and get the RSA key back.

Code for key generation and writing to file :

```
public void generate() throws Exception{

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kpair = kpg.genKeyPair();

    byte[] publicKeyBytes = kpair.getPublic().getEncoded();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("publicKey");
    fos.write(publicKeyBytes);
    fos.close();
}
```

Code for reading and getting back the RSA public key :

```
public static Key getKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws Exception{
    Key pk = null;
    File f = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    pk = kf.generatePublic(spec);
    return pk;
}
```

When I run the program I get the following error :

```
algid parse error, not a sequence
```

Cannot figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @rpax : Hey, you're right. It works. I had tried to edit the public key file manually because of which it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have the same exatc problem, @Lawrence can you please explain me what rpax told you? His comment is now deleted for whatever reason!

Comment: @LorenzoPiersante (and anyone who stumbles across this question) [have a look here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-rsa)